# Можно ли записать в защищенную ячейку из события по onEdit()?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Есть таблица в ней лист. Лист защищен с ограничением А1 в которую пользователь может вносить данные. Как при срабатывании onEdit() эти данные проверяя занести в А2. Пользователю триггер не дает такого права но может как то в скрипте это можно сделать ?

Answer (score 0):

Измените контекст запуска скрипта - зарегистрируйте его от имени пользователя, который имеет право вносить изменения. Обычно, это владелец Таблицы. И все будет работать.

Comment: Вы не могли бы  рассказать это сделать ? Учитывая что владелец таблицы дает пользователю заполнить определенные ячейки где в onEdit() проводит проверку и после внесения изменяет саму таблицу.